# Chrome: Trying to delete empty span in contenteditable results in added node

Tags: html, google-chrome, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable element that contains text and any number of non-contenteditable `span` elements.  The `span` elements sometimes have no text value (i.e. `<span></span>`) with a value displayed using an `:after` pseudo-node.

```
  <div class="basic-editor" contenteditable="true">
    <p>
      <span contenteditable="false" data-name="something"></span>
      Some text in between variables
      <span contenteditable="false" data-name="something"></span>
      <span contenteditable="false" data-name="something"></span>

      ...
    </p>
  </div>
```

The problem I have encountered occurs when trying to use the Delete key (not the backspace) to remove one of the "empty" `span` elements to the right of cursor.  What ends up happening is that the element is not deleted and, instead, a duplicate of the last `span` element in the contenteditable element is added/cloned.

Related observations:

- Happens in Chrome, but not Safari (have not tried FF or IE)

  - Target at this point is Chrome
- Does not happen when the `span` elements use a non-inline display
- Adding any content to the `span` resolves the issue: e.g. `<span> </span>`, `<span>&nbsp;</span>`
- Even just trying to move the cursor up-to and past the `span` elements using the arrow keys has some strange behaviour:  The cursor seems to get "stuck" and it takes an extra press of the arrow key to move past the `span`

Here is simple application that replicates the problem:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-vszw6c?file=index.html

Simply move the cursor in front of any of the blue `spans` and press the Delete key (again, not backspace).  Notice a duplicate of the last `span` gets added and the element being deleted remains unless the Delete key is pressed again.  If you continue pressing the Delete key, this will repeat for each empty `span` element.

I have found lots of issues related to `contenteditable` in Chrome and other browsers, but nothing that seems to match this issue.

I am assuming this is a Chrome/Chromium bug, but was hoping there might be other workarounds...